# Printing a variable from a C routine

Tags: c

I do not know how to use "C", but have a working C program that I need to print a 
program variable to determine what the program is doing. Can you tell me the easiest
way to do this
Jack

Comment: do you want to track the variable?

Comment: You can run program in debugger to see what is program doing.

Comment: do you need a debbug info or just standard printing?

Answer (score 1):

to print on stdout use `printf` function from `stdio.h`

Answer (score 0):

To watch the values of a particular variable in Turbo c (windows)
Window-> watch -> enter your variable name. Then Press F7.
You can able to keep track the value of the variable.